# How do I assign a sharepoint 2013 task to someone in VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ado

Here is my code, I'm in using VBA.  I get no errors, the task is added to the sharepoint list, but the Assigned To field is blank.

I have also listed all the fields in the recordset and there is no Assignment field available.  I noticed some unanswered questions on the web about how to query the value of a lookup field.

```
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
"DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
"LIST=" & sTASK_LIST_GUID & ";"

' Create some new objects.
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection.
With cn
.ConnectionString = sConn
.Open
End With

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Tasks] as tbl;"

' Open up the recordset.
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
With rs
    .AddNew
    ![Task Name] = "test"
    AssignedTo = "SomeEmailAddress"
    ![Categories] = "Data Requests"
    .Update
End With
rs.Close
```

I do know how to do this if I "connect with Outlook", but I was trying to avoid all that.

Answer (score 0):

The value would have to be in the format of `LookupId;#LookupValue`

Where **LookupId** is the user's ID for that particular site and the **LookupValue** is the users Display Name

So you would have:

AssignedTo = "48;#Chris McKay"

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, still nothing.  No error, and also no AssignedTo value showing in my list